# "Expected value" of Thirteen card game !!

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Thirteen cards numbered $1$ to $13$ are shuffled and dealt one at a time.

"Match" occurs on deal $k$ if $k$th card revealed is card number $k$

Let N be the total number of matches that occur in the thirteen cards. Determine $E[N]$

Hi, the above is the problem that I have a trouble with.

My first approach is that probability of first card with number $1$ is $\frac{1}{13}$ 
and probability of second card with number  $2$ is $\frac{1}{12}$.

It keeps going until last card, so I think $E[N]$ is $\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{11}\cdots+1$

I don't think this is right.

There is a hint saying that "Write $N= 1{A1}+1{A2}+....+1{A13}$, where $A_k$ is the event that a match occurs on deal $k$"

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hint: For each card, what is the probability that it will have a match?  Is it different for different cards?

Comment: The standard thing is to let $X_i=1$ if there is a match on the $i$-th pick, and $0$ otherwise. The number of matches is $X_1+\cdots +X_{13}$. Now use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: ins't probability of having a match 1/13?

Comment: There are 13 cards and For i-th pick, probability of having card with i number is 1/13. So, E[N]=E[X1+X2+....X13]= 1?  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's it precisely.